# What is the the "Other Memory" is db2mtrk

Tags: db2, database-administration, db2-luw

For example if I run `db2mtrk -a -v` it gives something like

```
Memory for application 1234

    Application Heap is of size 131072 bytes
    Other Memory is of size 262144 bytes
    Total: 393216 bytes
```

I can see the Application Heap size when I run `db2pd -db foo -mempools` from the physical size but I can't figure out where they get the Other memory total from.

I did a google search and couldn't come up with anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [db2mtrk](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008712.html) which states:

> "The "Other Memory" reported is the memory associated with the usage
>   of operating the database management system."

and there are more details on the [memory-allocation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005383.html) page showing how that is made up.

Comment: Thanks for that, I completely missed that documentation. Is there any other command to get more detailed info on the Other Memory or is this it?

Answer (score 0):

It's more convenient to use the following.

```
select 
  p.member
, coalesce(a.application_handle, p.application_handle) application_handle
, p.memory_pool_type
, p.edu_id
, p.memory_pool_used, p.memory_pool_used_hwm 
, c.application_id, c.coord_member
from table(mon_get_memory_pool(null, current server, -2)) p
left join table(wlm_get_service_class_agents(null, null, null, -2)) a on a.dbpartitionnum=p.member and a.agent_tid=p.edu_id
left join table(mon_get_connection(null, -2)) c on c.application_handle=coalesce(a.application_handle, p.application_handle) and c.member=p.member
where 1234 in (a.application_handle, p.application_handle)
;
```